# How to get request url who used my webapi in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, web-applications

> I already write a Web API method, now I want to get a client website URL who used my API method.

I tried this line of code but I get my API URL. But I want a client URL.

```
var requestUrl = Request.Url;
```

Comment: What you mean under _"client URL"_?

Comment: You can get the IP and the host name of the client, but not the "client URL". Take a look to: http://www.triconsole.com/dotnet/httprequest_class.php#urlreferrer

Comment: When you call an API, you usually don't send along a `Referer`header like a browser does. So to my knowledge, you can't get the URL. You can get the IP address though and do a reverse DNS lookup, but that will give you the users address - not the address of the website they're using.

Comment: If CORS is working: `Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var clientRequest = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"];
```